# Confirm message box return error value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a script for a confirm pop up window.When I call this in our aspx.cs page it returns different values.My script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
    confirm_value.type = "hidden";
    confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
    if (confirm("Do you want to remove this employee from this group?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "1";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "2";
    }
    document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
}
```

Button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd"  OnClientClick = "Confirm()" runat="server"    ValidationGroup="1" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
```

Button click function

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
        if (confirmValue == "1")
        {
          //Do something
        }
      else
       {
    //Do something
       }

    }
```

First time I clicked cancel then my `confirmvalue=="1"` and next time again I selected ok  then my `confirmvalue=="1,2"`in place of 2. How it returns error value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating multiple inputs named "confirm_value", one each time you're clicking the button. What you need to do is reuse the same input:

```
function Confirm() {
    var confirm_value = document.querySelector('[name="confirm_value"]');
    if (!confirm_value) {
        confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
    if (confirm("Do you want to remove this employee from this group?")) {
        confirm_value.value = "1";
    } else {
        confirm_value.value = "2";
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Confirm() {
var Result=confirm("Do you want to remove this employee from this group?");
var confirm_value = document.querySelector('[name="confirm_value"]');
 if (Result) {
return true;
 } else {
return false;
}    
}
```